# Sentence splitted into two

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently making an app and I would like the sentence to be on a single line. However, right now they are both separated. I will attach a link to the pic of how it is looking right now.

update: I have added the entire code as requested.

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-title title-a"><div id="lblFrom"></div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-title title-b"><div id="lblTo"></div></div>
    <div class=ui-block-a><input type="text" name="fromamount" id="fromamount" required /></div>
    <div class=ui-block-b><input type="text" name="toamount" id="toamount" required /></div>
    </div>

    <p>You are currently converting <div id="lblConversioning"></div></p>

    <input type="button" value="Conversion" id="btnConversion">

</div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M76KP.jpg

Comment: Could you provide entire code of your form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`div` is a *block element*. Use inline element *`span`* instead of div.

```
<p>You are currently converting <span id="lblConversioning"></span></p>
```

Comment: Hello! Yes, it is working the way I would like it to be. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

`div` is block element and by default display on new line.

Change it to span:

```
<p>You are currently converting <span id="lblConversioning"></span></p>
```

Or display it inline:

```
<p style="display: inline-block">You are currently converting <div style="display: inline-block" id="lblConversioning"></div></p>
```

Using `span` is better in this case

Answer (score 1):

`<div>` is a block level element. It would display the content in it by creating a new block in the document. You need to add extra styling if you want to display the content in `<div>` tags in a single line.

The best alternative is to use `<span>` instead.

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-title title-a"><div id="lblFrom"></div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-title title-b"><div id="lblTo"></div></div>
    <div class=ui-block-a><input type="text" name="fromamount" id="fromamount" required /></div>
    <div class=ui-block-b><input type="text" name="toamount" id="toamount" required /></div>
    </div>

    <p>You are currently converting <span id="lblConversioning"></span></p>

    <input type="button" value="Conversion" id="btnConversion">

</div>
```